# Data not loading in master textbox after Devexpress gridview events

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

Hi i am new to devexpress gridview. i have a textbox(TotalDebit) outside grid and i have a devex gridview in which i am inserting,updating data. In my event handler when i insert new row in gridview i want to calculate the total debit and show in the master textbox outside gridview. i have calculated the total debit but the problem is it is not showing in the textbox outside gridview. Here is the code:

public void grvDetail_RowInserting(objectsender,DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataInsertingEventArgs e)
    {

if (DetailTable.Rows.Count > 0)

```
           for (int i = 0; i < DetailTable.Rows.Count; i++)
           {

               if (DetailTable.Rows[i]["FlagDC"].ToString() == "D")
                   TotalDebit += Convert.ToDouble(DetailTable.Rows[i]["Amount"].ToString());
               else
                   TotalCredit += Convert.ToDouble(DetailTable.Rows[i]["Amount"].ToString());

           }

       txtDebit.Text = TotalDebit.ToString(); //textbox outside gridview
       txtCredit.Text = TotalCredit.ToString(); //textbox outside gridview

          }
```

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress support directly?

Answer (score 0):

See the [Why is it impossible to update external control data during a callback to another control](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18609) KB for explanation.